# Git LFS migrate: Importing all file types specified in .gitattributes?

Tags: git, git-lfs, git-lfs-migrate

After installing Git LFS, and creating a `.gitattributes` file with file types to track, I'd like to now run the `git lfs migrate` command for all file types specified in the `.gitattributes`. How can I do this?

All the sources I've found seem to only do either a single file type at a time, or a list of file type separated by a comma:

```
$ git lfs migrate import --include='*.psd'
```

```
$ git lfs migrate import --include='*.psd,*.jpg'
```

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is `git lfs migrate import --fixup`

Here's the [documentation](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/master/docs/man/git-lfs-migrate.1.ronn#import) for `git lfs migrate import`, which states:

> `--fixup` Infer `--include` and `--exclude` filters on a per-commit basis based on the .gitattributes files in a repository. In practice, this
>   option imports any filepaths which should be tracked by Git LFS
>   according to the repository's .gitattributes file(s), but aren't
>   already pointers. This option is incompatible with explicitly given
>   `--include`, `--exclude` filters.

Answer (score -1):

**include large files with specific extensions:**

```
$ git lfs migrate import --include='*.psd'
```

**include large files with multiple extensions:**

```
$ git lfs migrate import --include='*.psd,*.mp4'
```

**include large files with any extensions:**

```
$  git lfs migrate import --everything --include="*.*"
```