# How to fix git lfs migrate import changes? Revert Stored with Git LFS

Tags: git, github, command-line-interface, git-lfs, revert

Problem: `git lfs migrate import` converted everything to hash including .gitignore and all plaintext files.

Locally I gained 10k untracked files in .cache and .vscode-server maps that I do not want to track.

Even worse I can't edit any text files -> everything turned into 3 line file with hash!

Remote Github files now all are: Stored with Git LFS

Even my .gitignore looks like as follows:

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:5dc008478f60b91b2ca91405adf351b4d253a254cd77604fe3a86bba855eac8e
size 7036
```

Short history

- Local git repo added a large .bak file. Push to remote(Github) thus
  failed.
- Installed LFS locally (technically a different dev machine
  via SSH)

```
    git lfs install
    git lfs track "*.bak"
    git add .gitattributes
    git lfs status
    git lfs migrate
    git lfs migrate info
    git lfs migrate import
    git pull
    git push
```

Last 3 lines must be bad mistakes - especially **git lfs migrate import**

I should have specified which file types to import.
See [Git LFS git lfs migrate import include all file types specified in .gitattribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62014426/git-lfs-git-lfs-migrate-import-include-all-file-types-specified-in-gitattribute)

My .gitattributes file turns out to contain all extensions

```
*.bak filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.bash_history filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.gitignore filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.ipynb filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.md filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.zip filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.json filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
*.txt filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

more file types follow

I only wanted to convert .bak (and possibly .zip) to LFS.

How do I fix this mess?

First priority is getting original text files(.txt, .gitignore, .json, .md, .html etc) back locally.

Second priority is actually pushing to remote.

Comment: Do you have a backup of the repository from before the "migrate" operation? That's probably the easiest place to go. Otherwise: let git-LFS do the working-tree-file substitutions, copy the working-tree files out for each commit you want to redo, then build a new Git repository one commit at a time and throw away the old one (this will be painful).

Comment: No backup, I guess I could clone the revision from Github before LFS was added, then manually add the missing files one by one.

Comment: Yes, that's the painful option.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep using Git LFS but just want to restore files to have their contents, use [`git lfs checkout`](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/blob/main/docs/man/git-lfs-checkout.1.ronn).

Answer (score 0):

So far the least painful answer was to revert manually by each file type

```
 git lfs migrate export --include="*.gitignore" --everything
 git lfs migrate export --include="*.json" --everything
```

and so on

PS. This involved manually upgrading git-lfs from 2.3.4 to 3.0.2
as **git lfs migrate export** was simply broken in Ubuntu 18.04LTS version.

EDIT: turns out this only works for the local version as now I can't pull from remote. Naturally no push either.

```
> git pull --tags origin master
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories
```

So now I will have to create a new remote...